# Android Constraint Layout Editor Issue

Tags: java, android, layout, android-constraintlayout

recently I ran into a problem and have no idea whats wrong. So I was using Constraint Layout via Layout Editor and something happened that all views,textviews,etc... in editor locked into top left corner, however app works correctly, so I believe it's editor's fault. Any ideas how to fix this ?

[image: Image Example]

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to to File->Invalidate Caches / Restart.